# Lotus Notes (and MS Outlook) .ICS event CANCELLATION

Tags: outlook, interop, lotus-notes, icalendar

I am trying to implement external appointment management (using `VCAL2`) - namely `CREATE`, `UPDATE` and `CANCEL` appointment - and I need it to work with *Lotus Notes* (and possibly in *MS Outlook*).

My VCAL2 files are in my opinion correct (RFC 5545), and `CREATE` and `UPDATE` actually works well. Problem is only with `CANCEL` and only in *MS Outlook* and *Lotus Notes* - they seem to ignore the cancellation request.

**CREATE.ics**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//myprod//ical-poc//SK
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-RELCALID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T090000
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T093000
SUMMARY:CREATED
ATTENDEE:mailto:valid@email.xxx
DESCRIPTION:Event description.
ORGANIZER:mailto:cal-poc@domain.com
DTSTAMP:20150630T182305Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**UPDATE.ics**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//myprod//ical-poc//SK
METHOD:REQUEST
X-WR-RELCALID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T110000
SEQUENCE:1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T113000
SUMMARY:UPDATED+2
ATTENDEE:mailto:valid@email.xxx
DESCRIPTION:Event description.
ORGANIZER:mailto:cal-poc@domain.com
DTSTAMP:20150630T182428Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**CANCEL.ics**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//myprod//ical-poc//SK
METHOD:CANCEL
X-WR-RELCALID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T110000
SEQUENCE:1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CANCELLED
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T113000
SUMMARY:CREATED+2
ATTENDEE:mailto:valid@email.xxx
DESCRIPTION:Event description.
ORGANIZER:mailto:cal-poc@domain.com
DTSTAMP:20150630T182457Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As almost always, answering my question (it seems, posting it on S/O gives me some superpowers to find an answer in the next few hours).

It seems, there are multiple combinations of properties in `iCal` format, that form the valid file for each client. Following is my analysis of it (please note, it does not support RSVPs, but RSVPs only require few more tweaks to the file like slightly different methods etc. and the point of the question was cancellation):

**CREATE & UPDATE APPOINTMENT**

*All Applications:*

- `METHOD` must be `PUBLISH`
- `DTSTART` and `DTEND` (or `DURATION`) present
- `SEQUENCE` must be incremented on each update
- `ORGANIZER` must be present
- `UID` must be present
- `X-WR-RELCALID` for Outlook must be present and equal to `UID`
- `PRODID` must be present
- `STATUS` should be `CONFIRMED`

**CANCEL**

*All Applications:*

- `STATUS` must be `CANCELLED`
- all other fields as above

*Apple Calendar:*

- `METHOD` must be `PUBLISH` (or actually, must not be `CANCEL`)
- `DURATION` (or `DTEND`) must be present

*Microsoft Outlook:*

- `METHOD` must be `CANCEL`
- `DURATION` (or `DTEND`) **MUST NOT** be present

*Lotus Notes:*

- `METHOD` must be `CANCEL`
- `DURATION` (or `DTEND`) must be present

Comment: Thank you. The key for me with Lotus Notes was ensuring the intial event had the STATUS CONFIRMED otherwise the CANCEL didnt get picked up

Comment: This is craziness, doing exactly the same, just for Google calendar instead of Lotus Notes.

Comment: But it's still not cancelling the event in Outlook :(