# Is it even possible to cancel Outlook event using .ics? Please, provide me working .ics content for my event if so

Tags: outlook, icalendar, schedule, cancellation

I have common .ics for Google calendar/Apple calendar/Outlook for creating, rescheduling and cancelling calendar event, everything works except the cancelling of the event in Outlook.
I use Outlook.com so I guess it 's the latest Outlook version.

Create (works):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Travelport//NONSGML GOL Mobile//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Flight 
 from A 
 to B
UID:3d87d036-ad91-4576-b362-6a3529657305
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTART:20240713T171001
DTEND:20240713T171002
DTSTAMP:20231023T120600
LOCATION:airport A, city A
GEO:0;0
DESCRIPTION:Flight 
 from A 
 terminal 1, 
 city A 
 to B 
 terminal 1, 
 city B
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Update (works):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Travelport//NONSGML GOL Mobile//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Flight 
 from A 
 to B
UID:3d87d036-ad91-4576-b362-6a3529657305
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTART:20240713T172001
DTEND:20240713T172002
DTSTAMP:20231023T120599
LOCATION:airport A, city A
GEO:0;0
DESCRIPTION:Flight 
 from A 
 terminal 1, 
 city A 
 to B 
 terminal 1, 
 city B
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Cancel (does not work):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Travelport//NONSGML GOL Mobile//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Flight 
 from A 
 to B
UID:3d87d036-ad91-4576-b362-6a3529657305
SEQUENCE:2
STATUS:CANCELLED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTART:20240713T172001
DTEND:20240713T172002
DTSTAMP:20231023T120598
LOCATION:airport A, city A
GEO:0;0
DESCRIPTION:Flight 
 from A 
 terminal 1, 
 city A 
 to B 
 terminal 1, 
 city B
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I followed suggestions from [Why is my .ics file not registering a cancel event when it is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227488/why-is-my-ics-file-not-registering-a-cancel-event-when-it-is-opened), [How to cancel an calendar event using ics files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551764/how-to-cancel-an-calendar-event-using-ics-files), [With .ics files can I delete old events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566635/with-ics-files-can-i-delete-old-events), [Lotus Notes (and MS Outlook) .ICS event CANCELLATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146307/lotus-notes-and-ms-outlook-ics-event-cancellation) and other places, but it didn't help.

For example when I followed the last link, I get:
Create (works):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//myprod//ical-poc//SK
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-RELCALID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T090000
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T093000
SUMMARY:CREATED
ATTENDEE:mailto:valid@email.xxx
DESCRIPTION:Event description.
ORGANIZER:mailto:cal-poc@domain.com
DTSTAMP:20150630T182305Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Cancel (does not work):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//myprod//ical-poc//SK
METHOD:CANCEL
X-WR-RELCALID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5EF979C9-3764-4B55-93B8-3BB00DFA176C@uniq.id
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20150701T110000
SEQUENCE:1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:CREATED+2
ATTENDEE:mailto:valid@email.xxx
DESCRIPTION:Event description.
ORGANIZER:mailto:cal-poc@domain.com
DTSTAMP:20150630T182457Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```